# How to solve undefined references in C when linking with an external library that uses name space?

Tags: c, linker

I am linking my program to an external static library.

This is one of the many errors I am seeing:

```
undefined reference to `tcp_outratectl_tmofactor'
```

This is defined in a external library c file as:

```
int tcp_outratectl_tmofactor = 1;
```

This is used in my program as shown:

```
/* This is just a snippet */
extern int tcp_outratectl_timerticks;
if (count) {
    tcp_outratectl_timerticks = *count;
}
```

I extracted the object files from the library and tried to look for the symbol

```
$ nm -A ./*.o | grep tcp_outratectl_timerticks
./tcp_timer.o:0000000000000018 B rumpns_tcp_outratectl_timerticks
./tcp_usrreq.o:                 U rumpns_tcp_outratectl_timerticks
```

As you can see, the tcp_outratectl_tmofactor is a Global BSS symbol but it has "rumpns_" prefixed behind it and this is causing a linker error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you linking against C or C++?

Comment: I am linking against C

Comment: That is very strange, I thought C does not do name mangling of any sort.

Comment: The library that I linking is a NetBSD Library. It is written completely in C.

https://github.com/rumpkernel/src-netbsd

Comment: @merlin2011, C has some mangling scheme, at least for functions, to distinguish among different calling conventions.

Comment: @EricZ, I learn something new every day. :)

Comment: `extern int rumpns_tcp_outratectl_timerticks;` ?

Comment: or try `extern "C" { int tcp_outratectl_timerticks; }`, which would help avoid name mangling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external library which I am using adds "rumpns_" behind symbols that are not already a part of its namespace.

Modifying the makefile to remove this behavior worked for me